90 days resignation notice and PTO
Submitted a 90 ds resignation notice on 7/22 with the last day on 10/4 (76 days total) since I factored in PTO I already have now plus additional time off I would've accrued after working for 12 weeks. Employer demands I work till 10/22 (91 days) and return the full amount of sign on bonus paid to me over first 15 weeks of my employment.
Sadly I lasted only 7 months in this place due to toxic environment. Contract does not specify the time frame for $$ return, just says "to be paid back if employment is terminated within first year. Today I was given  2 options to repay: either lump sum for the full amount (I had obviously received significantly less due to taxes taken out) or have them to withhold moneys every paycheck spread over the final 90 days of employment.
Business is in Massachusetts.
Questions:

Given such long resignation notice I am entitled to use PTO that I would have earned after working for 3 months? I am starting new job on 10/22 and feel like I need some time off in between.
Are there any legal ramifications for leaving earlier?
Also, given lack of specific terms of return can I state I will return the full amount over the course of 30 days upon termination of the employment?

Thank you!


:Given such long resignation notice I am entitled to use PTO that I would have earned after working for 3 months?

Massachusetts is an at-will state, i.e. you don't have to give any notice at all unless it's specifically required in your employment contract. So you need to check your contract and/or company handbook (policies). 90 days is unusually long for Massachusetts. So it may be prudent to consult a employment lawyer and check if contract asking for it is enforceable.

Are there any legal ramifications for leaving earlier?

Not from the state, but your employer can come after you for breach of contract and potential damages. Whether they actually would is questionable. Again, best would be to discuss this with a lawyer.

I had obviously received significantly less due to taxes taken out

You will get your taxes back when you do your tax return next. For now you can reduce your withholding (using a W4 form) to recoup some of the taxes earlier.

or have them to withhold moneys every paycheck spread over the final 90 days of employment.

That seems like a reasonable approach.

If you are extremely lucky, the time off you would have earned after seven  months would be a few days. Even if they were being generous, if you took more than that you probably owe them money.
But it sounds like your contract is not that generous. If the contract, which you agreed to, says you owe them repayment, you owe them repayment.

In the US if the notice period is the typical two weeks, they expect that you will not take any PTO. They expect this because they want to get those 80 hours of work so you can finish some items, provide a little training, and get ready to leave.
When the notice period is longer, and 90 days is a long notice period they aren't surprised that a little PTO used.

Submitted a 90 ds resignation notice on 7/22 with the last day on 10/4
(76 days total) since I factored in PTO I already have now plus
additional time off I would've accrued after working for 12 weeks.
Employer demands I work till 10/22 (91 days)
...
I am starting new job on 10/22 and feel like I need some time off in between.

When an employee wants to stop a few weeks earlier, and then take the rest in cash via PTO they assume that means you will be starting your new job the day after the last day you will be in the office.

Sadly I lasted only 7 months in this place due to toxic environment

Normally a departing employee wants to minimize their use of PTO so that they get a big PTO payout.
In your case you want to minimize the number of days in the office. Their reaction is expected. They want as much work from you as they can get. Of course if they are too toxic they risk getting zero productive work for their money.
If you took leave in September, and then worked to October 22nd, that might make them happier.

Employer demands I work till 10/22 (91 days) and return the full
amount of sign on bonus paid to me over first 15 weeks of my
employment.
Sadly I lasted only 7 months in this place due to toxic environment.
Contract does not specify the time frame for $$ return, just says "to
be paid back if employment is terminated within first year. Today I
was given 2 options to repay: either lump sum for the full amount (I
had obviously received significantly less due to taxes taken out) or
have them to withhold moneys every paycheck spread over the final 90
days of employment.

This is typical when you have to reimburse them for training classes, educational assistance, signing bonus, or moving expenses. If you don't want to pay it back, you have to wait until the end of listed time period before giving notice.
Since you are at 7 months and 90 more days will take you to 10 months, it looks like you will have to pay them back.  This is case where having a 90 day notice period is good, otherwise you could be wring them a check on your last day of work.

Are there any legal ramifications for leaving earlier?

That is what you are experiencing with the requirement to pay them back.

Also, given lack of specific terms of return can I state I will return
the full amount over the course of 30 days upon termination of the
employment?

You can always ask. They may be flexible. But they also realize that once you are gone, they will have a hard time getting you to write a check.  Depending on how much you owe, and your PTO balance it may be possible to pay them from the PTO balance, or at least reduce what you owe.

I think it's more accurate to say that typical pay period is bi-weekly, which is the reason a reasonable notice period is typically 2 weeks but would go onto to say that your notice period should be limited to a single pay period.

I have been paid weekly, every two weeks, twice a month, and monthly. The normal notice period was two week for all those companies.

I am not an attorney.  There is a concept in law called anticipatory breach, that might apply in your situation.  By giving noticed prior to the one-year mark, you have demonstrated your intention to breach the contract for the training.  Even though you are still working, the company has grounds for legal actions against you right now even though the year hasn't elapsed.  Of course, they don't want the expense of court costs and attorneys, so they're trying to do things with you the easy way.
What I'm reading in several places is that in your state, employers may deduct from current wages if there is a "clear and established debt".  Well, looks like they have one based on your breach.
Again, I'm not an attorney.  If the place is as miserable as you say, even staying 76 days will be rough.  They want you to work it out over 90 days.  If you are going to stay and work off the debt, you need to have a written agreement between you and the company that makes it clear what you're doing and how much money they'll be deducting.  Avoid agreeing to any penalties.  Keep in the back of your mind that if the amount is significant, they might sue you based on if they think they can collect after a judgment from a court.
Personally, I wouldn't stick around in a toxic situation.
